# Center two columns side by side

Tags: html, css

The problem that im encountering is that I have put a wrapper in the center of the page (content) and within the wrapper there are two columns (text and form).

I'm trying to put them side by side, however, every time that I'm doing it the form column moves to the right. I want them to be centered side by side and when you re-size the browser it breaks like facebook.com.

```css
#header,
#content,
#footer {
        display:inline;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        background-color:#eee;
      }
#header,
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display:inline;
    position:relative;
   float:left;
        background-color:#eee;
}
#content {
  padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%; 
  max-height:600px;
  margin:0 auto;
  
}

   
}
#header {
  margin-bottom:2%;
}
#footer {
  margin-top:2%;
  width:100%;
        height:60px;
}
h2 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

h2:before {
  background: #ddd;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
h2:before {
  left: 0;
}
#login_form{
 margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    border: 0px solid none;
    padding: 10px;
}
#registration_form{
 text-align: center; 
 margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    border: 0px solid none;
    padding: 10px;
}
.login{
 text-align: center; 
}
.username{
  margin: auto;
    width: 70%;
    border: 0px solid none;
    padding: 10px;
}
.content{
 margin-right: 16px;
 width:560px; 
 float:left; 
 left:80px;
}
.sidebar{
 width: 395px;
 display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
 float:right; 
 right: 80px;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"><header>header<header>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
            Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
            ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec,
            vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
            Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.
            Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet.
            Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus,
            sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio
            et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo.
            Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,<p>
        </div>


        <div class="sidebar">
            <h2><span>Login</span></h2>
            <form>
                <div id="login_form">
                    <div class="username">
                        Username<input type="text" name="username"><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="login" value="login">Keep me logged in<br>
                        Password<input type="password" name="password"><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login">
                        <a href="">Forgot your password?</a><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Log In"><br>
                        or<br>
                        <input type="button" value="Facebook"><input type="button" value="Google+"><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>


            <h2><span>Sign Up</span></h2>
            <form>
                <div id="registration_form">
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="First name">
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Last name"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="Email">
                    <input type="text" name="username" value="Username"><br>
                    <input type="password" name="password" value="Password">
                    <input type="password" name="confpass" value="last name"><br>
                    <p>By clicking Sign Up, you agree to our <a href="">Terms</a>
                    and that you have read our <a href="">Data Policy</a>, including our <a href="">Cookie Use</a>.</p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="footer"><footer>footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't a social network, hashtags in your title will only result in you drawing the attention of our amazing down-voting community

Comment: Apart from that, you need to 1: Write your actual problem in the title(make it short) 2: You need to make your question as concise as possible, and thoroughly explain the problem, and the desired results. [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: header, content and footer as *inline* elements *and* `float: left` *and* 100% width? Sorry, but this CSS code doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `#content` should be centre aligned. To do that you either can give it a `width` value and `margin:auto;` or you can give it a percentage width with percentage padding. In this case I used the percentage way.

To make the `.content` and `.sidebar` right next to each other you either need `width:50%;` (or any ratio) with `display:inline-block;` or `float:left;` on both the elements. Here I have used `float:left;`.

I could not see the page properly on the small result window of the editor. So keep in mind that this will only work on large devices. To make it work on smaller/mobile devices you need to use **CSS media queries**.

```css
#header,
#content,
#footer {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #eee;
}
#header,
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #eee;
}
#content {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px 10%;
}
}
#header {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
#footer {
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
h2 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
h2:before {
  background: #ddd;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
h2:before {
  left: 0;
}
#login_form {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  border: 0px solid none;
  padding: 10px;
}
#registration_form {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  border: 0px solid none;
  padding: 10px;
}
.login {
  text-align: center;
}
.username {
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  border: 0px solid none;
  padding: 10px;
}
.content {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/stylesheet.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <header>header
      <header>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
        quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
        dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius
        laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque
        sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis
        leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
        <p>
    </div>


    <div class="sidebar">
      <h2><span>Login</span></h2>
      <form>
        <div id="login_form">
          <div class="username">
            Username
            <input type="text" name="username">
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="login" value="login">Keep me logged in
            <br>Password
            <input type="password" name="password">
            <br>
          </div>
          <div class="login">
            <a href="">Forgot your password?</a>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Log In">
            <br>or
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="Facebook">
            <input type="button" value="Google+">
            <br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>


      <h2><span>Sign Up</span></h2>
      <form>
        <div id="registration_form">
          <input type="text" name="firstname" value="First name">
          <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Last name">
          <br>
          <input type="text" name="email" value="Email">
          <input type="text" name="username" value="Username">
          <br>
          <input type="password" name="password" value="Password">
          <input type="password" name="confpass" value="last name">
          <br>
          <p>By clicking Sign Up, you agree to our <a href="">Terms</a> and that you have read our <a href="">Data Policy</a>, including our <a href="">Cookie Use</a>.</p>
          <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <footer>footer</footer>
</body>

</html>
```